# Disconnected device still visible in /dev

Tags: linux, bluetooth, device-manager

When my Bluetooth GPS logger disconnects it's removed from the Bluetooth devices list in the statusbar on OS X but I can still see it mapped in `/dev`:

```
ls /dev/tty\.*
> /dev/tty.GPSDEVICE-SPPslave
```

Why is that? Why is the mapping still there even though the device is no longer available? Should I not depend on the `/dev` list to know what devices are connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Think** I know how it works. When you pair a device it shows up as a `/dev/tty.something` mapping and when you unpair the file disappears again. I assume it's the same as a hard drive mount where you create a mount point and have to unmount the drive when done.

Please correct me if I am wrong.